# SSH : Write failed: Broken pipe error

Tags: ssh

I connect with my work PC using SSH. It was working fine until recently but now suddenly connection gets lost with error "write failed: Broken pipe " error on terminal. I saw similar question somewhere and it was suggested to add "ServerAliveInterval 120" line in ssh_config file. it doesn't work and I am facing same error again.